# Read unstructured Excel payslip and export to structured Excel table

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I've not used this site before, I would like to get opinions on the code I've completed for my first 'program' in Python. I would like to understand how 'good' it is and where it can be improved, anything that says "you're clearly a beginner and haven't learned xxx" would be helpful.

Background to project: My payslips are in a weird format with info dotted around all over a spreadsheet and have slight variations in positioning month on month. For example the value of a field might not be in the adjacent cell it might be below it for one field and to the right for another (although this relative positioning is consistent month on month) I combined manually all the months into one Excel and wanted to structure the data so I could eventually run calculations on it to ensure it was correct and my taxes were correct (still need to do that part).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import openpyxl

def get_data(ws):
    data = []
    for y in range(1,ws.max_row + 1):
        rows = []
        for x in range(1,ws.max_column + 1):
            rows.append(ws.cell(column = x, row = y).value)
        data.append(rows)
    return data

def search_data(data, criteria):
    location = []
    for row in range(len(data)):
        for column in range(len(data[row])):
            if data[row][column] == criteria:
                location.append([row,column])
    if len(location) == 0:
        print('Not present on sheet')
        return None
    return location

def offset(location,rows,columns):
    location[0] = location[0] + rows
    location[1] = location[1] + columns
    return location

def get_table(data, startloc, columns=None):
    count = 1
    rows = 1
    table = []
    temprow = startloc[0]
    tempcol = startloc[1]
    while count != 0:    
        if data[temprow][tempcol] != None:
            temprow = temprow + 1
            if temprow == len(data):
                break
        else:
            count = 0
    rows = temprow - startloc[0]
    if columns == None:
        temprow = startloc[0]
        tempcol = startloc[1]
        count = 1
        while count != 0:
            if data[temprow][tempcol] != None:
                tempcol = tempcol + 1
                if tempcol == len(data[temprow]):
                    break
            else:
                count = 0
        columns = tempcol - startloc[1]
    for y in range(rows):
        table_rows = []
        for x in range(columns):
            table_rows.append(data[startloc[0]+y][startloc[1]+x])
        table.append(table_rows)
    return table

def get_value(data, location):
    return data[location[0]][location[1]]

def get_tax_info(ws):
    data = get_data(ws)
    tax_info = []
    #gets individual values
    tax_period = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'Calendar Month')[0],0,1))
    tax_period_ending = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'Calendar Month')[0],0,2))
    tax_code = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data, 'Tax Code')[0],1,0))
    tax_basis = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data, 'Tax Basis')[0],1,0))
    NI_category = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'NI Category')[0],1,0))
    total_payments = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'Total Payments')[0],1,0))
    net_pay = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'Net Pay')[0],1,0))
    #gets tables
    payments = get_table(data,offset(search_data(data,'Payments')[0],4,0))
    deductions = get_table(data,offset(search_data(data,'Deductions')[0],4,0))
    balances = get_table(data,offset(search_data(data,'Balances')[0],4,0))
    #combine
    tax_info.extend([tax_period, tax_period_ending, tax_code, tax_basis, NI_category, total_payments, net_pay])
    tax_info.append(payments)
    tax_info.append(deductions)
    tax_info.append(balances)
    return tax_info

class payslip:
    def __init__(self, tax_period, tax_period_ending, tax_code, tax_basis, NI_category, total_payments, net_pay, payments, deductions, balances):
        'Creates a payslip object with all the fields of the payslip'
        self.tax_period_ending = tax_period_ending
        self.tax_code = tax_code
        self.tax_basis = tax_basis
        self.NI_category = NI_category
        self.total_payments = total_payments
        self.net_pay = net_pay
        self.payments = payments
        self.deductions = deductions
        self.balances = balances

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('.../Payslips.xlsx')
sheet_names = wb.sheetnames        
payslips = []

for i in range(0,len(sheet_names)):
    each = sheet_names[i]
    ws = wb[each]
    tax_info = get_tax_info(ws)
    payslips.append(payslip(tax_info[0], tax_info[1], tax_info[2], tax_info[3], tax_info[4], tax_info[5], tax_info[6], tax_info[7],tax_info[8],tax_info[9]))

wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2.title = 'Payslips Summary'
ws2['A1'],ws2['B1'],ws2['C1'],ws2['D1'],ws2['E1'], ws2['F1'] = 'tax_period_ending', 'total_payments', 'net_pay', 'tax_code', 'NI_category', 'tax_basis'

for i in range(0,len(payslips)):
    ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=1).value = payslips[i].tax_period_ending
    ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=2).value = payslips[i].total_payments
    ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=3).value = payslips[i].net_pay
    ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=4).value = payslips[i].tax_code
    ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=5).value = payslips[i].NI_category
    ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=6).value = payslips[i].tax_basis

wb2.save('Payslips_Summary.xlsx')
```

Comment: Is this Python 3?

Comment: Yes it should be

Comment: It should be? You don't know?

Comment: @t3chb0t - I've set it up as Python 3, most resources I have used to learn this far have been Python 3 but it's not impossible that I have strayed into Python 2.7 as other than a few things like the print statement I'm not sure I would recognise the differences immediately and sometimes I still find resources in Python 2.7 which I'm still reading about to understand things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for x in range(1,ws.max_column + 1):
>     rows.append(ws.cell(column = x, row = y).value)
> ```

One of the biggest savers in overhead is [grabbing multiple cells at once](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells), instead of making multiple calls to get adjacent cell data.

---

> ```
> location = []
> for row in range(len(data)):
>     for column in range(len(data[row])):
>         if data[row][column] == criteria:
>             location.append([row,column])
> ```

Couple things here. [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is super helpful in getting both the index and the item itself.

```
location = []
for r, row in enumerate(data):
     for c, cell in enumerate(row):
         if cell == criteria:
             location.append([r,c])
```

Taking this a step further; since you are just creating a list, you can use a [list comprehentsion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to accomplish this in one go (with a nested `for`):

```
location = [[r,c] for r, row in enumerate(data) for c, cell in enumerate(row) if cell == criteria]
```

Almost looks like a mouthful, but it's easy to follow with the basic building blocks.

---

> ```
> if len(location) == 0:
> ```

Python understands that lists can be empty, so this can be simplified to just:

```
if not location:
```

---

> ```
> def offset(location,rows,columns):
>     location[0] = location[0] + rows
>     location[1] = location[1] + columns
>     return location
> ```

Makes sense to turn these into incrementors:

```
 def offset(location,rows,columns):
     location[0] += rows
     location[1] += columns
     return location
```

---

> ```
> count = 1 # Flag can be utilized differently, not needed
> rows = 1 # Gets reassigned later anyway, not needed
> table = [] # Can be used in a list comprehension assignment
> temprow = startloc[0]
> tempcol = startloc[1]
> ```

You can get away with some tuple assignment here:

```
temprow, tempcol = startloc
```

---

> ```
> while count != 0:    
>     if data[temprow][tempcol] != None:
>         temprow = temprow + 1
>         if temprow == len(data):
>             break
>     else:
>         count = 0
> ```

Seems like your actual loop condition is based on the first `if`:

```
 while data[temprow][tempcol] != None:
     temprow += 1
     if temprow == len(data):
         break
```

---

> ```
> if columns == None:
>     temprow = startloc[0]
>     tempcol = startloc[1]
>     count = 1
>     while count != 0:
>         if data[temprow][tempcol] != None:
>             tempcol = tempcol + 1
>             if tempcol == len(data[temprow]):
>                 break
>         else:
>             count = 0
> ```

Combining some of the previous items:

```
 if columns == None:
     temprow, tempcol = startloc
     while data[temprow][tempcol] != None:
         tempcol += 1
         if tempcol == len(data[temprow]):
             break
```

---

> ```
> for y in range(rows):
>     table_rows = []
>     for x in range(columns):
>         table_rows.append(data[startloc[0]+y][startloc[1]+x])
>     table.append(table_rows)
> ```

Another way to setup list comprehension by combining your `offset` and `get_value` functions:

```
table = [[get_value(data, offset(startloc, y, x)) for x in range(columns)] for y in range(rows)]
```

---

> ```
> tax_period = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'Calendar Month')[0],0,1))
> tax_period_ending = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'Calendar Month')[0],0,2))
> tax_code = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data, 'Tax Code')[0],1,0))
> tax_basis = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data, 'Tax Basis')[0],1,0))
> NI_category = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'NI Category')[0],1,0))
> total_payments = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'Total Payments')[0],1,0))
> net_pay = get_value(data,offset(search_data(data,'Net Pay')[0],1,0))
>
> #gets tables
> payments = get_table(data,offset(search_data(data,'Payments')[0],4,0))
> deductions = get_table(data,offset(search_data(data,'Deductions')[0],4,0))
> balances = get_table(data,offset(search_data(data,'Balances')[0],4,0))
> ```

These repeated calls to `get_table`, `get_value`, and `search_data`, perhaps you can refactor by adding a function that helps get the values you want with only the unique line differences.

---

> ```
> tax_info.extend([tax_period, tax_period_ending, tax_code, tax_basis, NI_category, total_payments, net_pay])
> tax_info.append(payments)
> tax_info.append(deductions)
> tax_info.append(balances)
> return tax_info
> ```

You may as well just return it all at once:

```
return [tax_period, tax_period_ending, tax_code, tax_basis, NI_category, total_payments, net_pay, payments, deductions, balances]
```

---

> ```
> class payslip:
>     def __init__(self, tax_period, tax_period_ending, tax_code, tax_basis, NI_category, total_payments, net_pay, payments, deductions, balances):
>         'Creates a payslip object with all the fields of the payslip'
>         self.tax_period_ending = tax_period_ending
>         self.tax_code = tax_code
>         self.tax_basis = tax_basis
>         self.NI_category = NI_category
>         self.total_payments = total_payments
>         self.net_pay = net_pay
>         self.payments = payments
>         self.deductions = deductions
>         self.balances = balances
> ```

Ideally, with all this data you're retreiving, seems like you'd be better suited to extend this class, that ingests `data`, and sets the fields into [Class properties](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) like you're already doing. Also, [class names should be capitalized](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#class-names).

```
class Payslip:
    def __init__(self, worksheet):
        'Creates a payslip object with all the fields of the payslip'
        self.data = self.get_data(worksheet)
        self.get_tax_info()

    def get_data(ws):
        # code for get_data here.

    def search(self, criteria):
        # search_data code here, substituting data with self.data
        # Should throw exception if not found.
        # Also good idea to incorporate offset function by adding params to this method

    def value(self, location):
        return self.data[location[0]][location[1]]

    def table(self, startloc, columns=None):
        # Get_table code here, substituting data with self.data

    @staticmethod
    def offset(location,rows,columns):
        # offset code here. This static method doesn't need data, but nice to be encapsulated

    def get_tax_info(self)
        # Add logic to figure out tax infos
        self.tax_period, self.tax_period_ending = tax_period, tax_period_ending
        self.tax_code, self.tax_basis, self.NI_category = tax_code, tax_basis, NI_category
        self.total_payments, self.net_pay = total_payments, net_pay
        self.payments, self.deductions, self.balances = payments, deductions, balances
```

---

> ```
> for i in range(0,len(sheet_names)):
>     each = sheet_names[i]
>     ws = wb[each]
> ```

Can just loop over sheetnames here:

```
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
    ws = wb[sheet]
```

---

> ```
> payslips.append(payslip(tax_info[0], tax_info[1], tax_info[2], tax_info[3], tax_info[4], tax_info[5], tax_info[6], tax_info[7],tax_info[8],tax_info[9]))
> ```

If you didn't expand your class definitions:

```
payslips.append(payslip(*tax_info))
```

But if you expanded your class definitions to do the processing, you can make this look so much cleaner by:

```
payslips.append(Payslip(ws))
```

---

> ```
> for i in range(0,len(payslips)):
>     ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=1).value = payslips[i].tax_period_ending
>     ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=2).value = payslips[i].total_payments
>     ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=3).value = payslips[i].net_pay
>     ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=4).value = payslips[i].tax_code
>     ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=5).value = payslips[i].NI_category
>     ws2.cell(row=i+2, column=6).value = payslips[i].tax_basis
> ```

As said earlier with accessing many cells, you should be able to grab the cells and assign them all in one swoop.

```
for rows in ws2['A2':'F'+len(payslips)+2]:
```

This will iterate through each row, setting you up for something nice. Next, you'll want to extend your `Payslips` class again with another method to return each of the field values:

```
def summary_data(self):
    yield self.tax_period_ending
    yield self.total_payments
    yield self.net_pay
    yield self.tax_code
    yield self.NI_category
    yield self.tax_basis
```

Using the [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield_stmt) keyword to create a generator that will return each of these items one at a time when you iterate through it.

Since we'll want to step through each `payslip` at the same time as each row, we can combine both by using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and accessing both together.

```
for rows, ps in zip(ws2['A2':'F'+len(payslips)+2], payslips):
    for cell, value in zip(rows, payslips.summary_data()):
        cell.value = value
```

Using the [slice notation to grab the cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells), we transformed your repeated calls, into a single call to the sheet to get `A2:F#` where # is the number of payslips + 2 (offset). We iterate over the rows to get cell data as well as the summary data values at the same time so that we can save it to the sheet.

---

Then finally you can wrap up your summary as you have with:

> ```
> wb2.save('Payslips_Summary.xlsx')
> ```

No issues there. I hope this helps, as this is one of my first reviews on here.